# Registered a REST Route but I’m Getting a 400 Bad Request

Tags: php, javascript, rest-api

I'm new to this so please bare with me. I'm trying to register a REST route to save the dynamically added custom fields of a custom post along with the post when the user clicks the "Update" button of the block editor. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I got the code from ChatGPT and customized it to the best of my knowledge but it keeps giving me a 400 Bad Request on the console.

Here is my JavaScript code:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  // Delete location event handler
  
  // Add a location event handler

  // Watch out for the save action
  wp.data.subscribe(function() {
    var editor = wp.data.select('core/editor');
    if (!editor) return;
    if (editor.isSavingPost() && !editor.isAutosavingPost()) {
      var locationsData = [];

      // Retrieve all the locations from the DOM
      var locationItems = document.querySelectorAll('.location-item');
      if (locationItems.length > 0) {
        locationItems.forEach(function(locationItem) {
          var i = locationItem.dataset.index;
          var locationData = {
            name: locationItem.querySelector('input[name^="guide-locations-' + i + '"]').value,
            description: wp.editor.getContent('guide-locations-' + i + '-description'),
            map: locationItem.querySelector('input[name^="guide-locations-' + i + '-map"]').value,
            wifi: locationItem.querySelector('input[name^="guide-locations-' + i + '-wifi"]').value,
            price: locationItem.querySelector('input[name^="guide-locations-' + i + '-price"]').value,
            hours: locationItem.querySelector('input[name^="guide-locations-' + i + '-hours"]').value,
          };
          locationsData.push(locationData);
        });
      }

      // Send a POST request to update the post meta
      fetch(guidePostsAjax.ajaxUrl + '/guide-posts/v1/save-locations/' + editor.getCurrentPostId(), {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'X-WP-Nonce': guidePostsAjax.nonce
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(locationsData)
      })
      .then(function(response) {
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error('An error occurred');
        }
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(function(data) {
        // Handle the response
        console.log(data);
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.error('An error occurred:', error);
      });
    }
  });

});
```

Here is the plugin's related PHP code:

```
// Register a custom REST route for saving guide locations
function save_guide_locations_rest_route() {
  register_rest_route(
    'guide-posts/v1',
    '/save-locations/(?P<post_id>\d+)',
    array(
      'methods' => 'POST',
      'callback' => 'save_guide_locations',
    )
  );
}
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'save_guide_locations_rest_route' );

// REST handler for saving guide locations
function save_guide_locations( $request ) {
  $post_id = $request->get_param( 'post_id' );

  // Validate parameter
  if ( empty( $post_id ) ) :
    return new WP_Error( 'invalid_params', 'Invalid parameters.', array( 'status' => 400 ) );
  endif;

  // Verify the nonce
  if ( ! isset( $_POST['guide_locations_nonce'] ) || ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['guide_locations_nonce'], 'guide_locations_nonce' ) ) :
    return new WP_Error( 'invalid_nonce', 'Invalid nonce.', array( 'status' => 403 ) );
  endif;

  // Get the locations data from the request body
  $body = $request->get_body();
  $locations_data = json_decode( $body, true );

  // Check if decoding the JSON was successful
  if ( is_null( $locations_data ) ) {
    return new WP_Error( 'json_decode_error', 'Failed to decode JSON data.', array( 'status' => 400 ) );
  }

  // Sanitize and save the locations data
  update_post_meta( $post_id, 'guide_locations', $locations_data );

  return array( 'message' => 'Guide locations saved successfully.' );
}
```

I mostly understand the code. I just don't know what I'm doing wrong. I tried doing this to check if the route exists but it's also giving me an error:

```
function check_rest_route() {
    if ( rest_route_exists( 'guide-posts/v1' ) ) {
        // The REST route has been registered.
        $message = 'The REST route exists.';
    } else {
        // The REST route has not been registered.
        $message = 'The REST route does not exist.';
    }

    // Output the message on the page
    wp_die( $message );
}
add_action( 'init', 'check_rest_route' );
```

Comment: The REST API can be hard to debug. Please first check if any of the default REST Endpoints can be reached. Nonces that are using with the REST API have to be created with the [`wp_rest`](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/) key. Try removing the body of the `save_guide_locations` function and simply return a message to see if the problem persists. Doing this will narrow down the issue.

Comment: I tried commenting out the whole callback except for function save_guide_locations( $request ) { } and replacing it with:
   $response = array( 'message' => 'Guide locations saved successfully.' );
  wp_send_json_success( $response );

The response was 0.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's the same but I think I'm doing this to create(?) a nonce:
    // Add inline script to pass the nonce value
    wp_add_inline_script( 'guide-posts', '
      var guidePostsAjax = {
        ajaxUrl: "' . esc_js( admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) . '",
        nonce: "' . esc_js( wp_create_nonce( 'guide_locations_nonce' ) ) . '"
      }'
    );

That one is in my 'enqueue_block_editor_assets'.

Comment: It's weird. The callback is done twice.

Comment: `admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )` will not create a URL to the REST API. You'll need [`rest_url('guide-posts/v1')`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/rest_url/) to get the correct URL. And `wp_create_nonce()` now creates a nonce with the key `guide_locations_nonce`, but that key should be `wp_rest`, otherwise it won't work.

Comment: Is that the reason why the response is 0? The nonce it's being passed is invalid?

Comment: It's because you're not contacting the right URL with `admin_url('admin-ajax.php')`. Just check your browser console and you'll see that the URL you're trying to reach isn't `yoursite.com/wp-json/guide-posts/v1/...`. Whenever you got that working, then the `nonce` will be an issue because the key isn't `wp_rest`.

Comment: Sorry. I was having a stupid moment. It took me a while to get that I need to change the inline script. I made the changes and admin_url('admin-ajax') is now rest_url('guide-posts/v1'). I have also changed guide_locations_nonce in wp_create_nonce() to wp_rest also. Now, I'm getting a 404 Not Found.

Comment: I corrected the URL in the JavaScript file and it's still giving me a 404. This is the response: {
    "code": "rest_no_route",
    "message": "No route was found matching the URL and request method.",
    "data": {
        "status": 404
    }
}

Comment: Okay, at least you're calling the REST API. You can manually check if the URL exists or if you need to make corrections by checking the avaiable routes. Go to `yoursite.com/wp-json` and find your registered route.

Comment: In the browser, the message was: No route was found matching the URL and request method. In the DevTool the message was: Invalid nonce. At least it's now checking the nonce. I have an esc_js() processing wp_create_nonce(). Does that affect that?

Comment: That message checks out, as you've registered a POST method. Visiting the URL in the browser will always use the GET method. You don't have to check the nonce inside of the callback anymore, WP does that for you. The nonce will just make it sure that you can't reach the endpoint from outside of your domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you're reaching the correct endpoint by using [`rest_url()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/rest_url/). When using the REST API and nonces, make sure that the nonce action is set to `'wp_rest'`.

```php
add_action('enqueue_block_editor_assets', function () {
  $data = wp_json_encode(array(
    'restUrl' => esc_js(rest_url('guide-posts/v1')),
    'nonce'   => esc_js(wp_create_nonce('wp_rest'))
  ));

  wp_add_inline_script('guide-posts', "var guidePostsAjax = $data"); 
});
```

The `permission_callback` property is mandatory when registering a REST route. Setting the value to `'__return_true'` will indicate that no additional permission checking needs to be done.

```
function save_guide_locations_rest_route() {
  register_rest_route(
    'guide-posts/v1',
    '/save-locations/(?P<post_id>\d+)',
    array(
      'methods'             => 'POST',
      'callback'            => 'save_guide_locations',
      'permission_callback' => '__return_true'
    )
  );
}
```

Remove the nonce validation entirely from the callback function. This will be handled by the REST API since we're using the `wp_nonce` action.

```
function save_guide_locations( $request ) {
  $post_id = $request->get_param( 'post_id' );

  // Validate parameter
  if ( empty( $post_id ) ) :
    return new WP_Error( 'invalid_params', 'Invalid parameters.', array( 'status' => 400 ) );
  endif;

  // Get the locations data from the request body
  $body = $request->get_body();
  $locations_data = json_decode( $body, true );

  // Check if decoding the JSON was successful
  if ( is_null( $locations_data ) ) {
    return new WP_Error( 'json_decode_error', 'Failed to decode JSON data.', array( 'status' => 400 ) );
  }

  // Sanitize and save the locations data
  update_post_meta( $post_id, 'guide_locations', $locations_data );

  return new WP_REST_Response(array('message' => 'Guide locations saved successfully.'));
}
```

Comment: It gave me a post edited successfully message on the console but now the block editor is not loading. It's just a blank page with markups. The block editor loads for the posts but not for the custom post type Guides. There's no error either.

Comment: Sorry, man. You have to do some debugging on your own as I feel like I've doing my best to help you out so far. Make sure that `WP_DEBUG` in your config is on, remove the latest code that you've added and re-add piece by piece to isolate the part that breaks the block editor.

Comment: And ChatGPT is great, but it isn't bulletproof - as you've clearly noticed. The best advice I ever got when starting out was *learning to read documentation*. It's like sheet music: if you know what notes to play, then you can figure out the song. Same applies to coding.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I did read the documentation just to understand the code ChatGPT gave me. Maybe not each and every piece of function, hook, or action but I made sure I understood the code generally.

Comment: Any chance you're using a Mac, Hombrew, and the PHP formula of Homebrew? I'm having a hard time accessing the error logs of PHP. I'm also debugging another issue and I already posted something about this.

Comment: I just found it! Sorry.

Comment: It finally works! Thank you so much for helping me debug this. I really appreciate it.